# grails: multiple belongsTo with back reference

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to have a domain class that belongs to multiple domain classes with back reference? For instance:

```
class Person {
    List<Book> books
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Organization {
    List<Books> books
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
    def owner // what's the type?
    static belongsTo = [Person, Books]
}
```

A Book can belong to a Person or an Organization, but not both.
Person and Organization have separate sequence IDs.

The solution I came up with is:

```
class Book {
    Long ownerID
    String ownerClass
    static belongsTo = [Person, Books]

    static transients = ['owner']

    static constraints = {
        ownerId(nullable:false, blank:false)
        ownerClass(nullable:false, blank:false)
    }

    public BookOwner getOwner() {
        grailsApplication.getArtefact("Domain", ownerClass)?.getClazz()?.get(ownerId)
    }
 }
```

where `BookOwner` is an Interface implemented by `Person` and `Organization`. So calling a `bookInstance.owner` will return a `Person` or `Organization` instance, both `BookOwner`.

My solution works well, but it doesn't feel right - a sure sign that I am not fully understanding what I'm doing. What's the best way to implement this? Should I completely give up on having the extremely convenient back reference?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should have made `Owner` superclass. Grails will create `Owner` table with field `class` meaning child class names (in your case: `Person`, `Organization`).